# Reading a double number from the console

Tags: c#, console, double

I am trying to read a number from the console, but if it is input via comma (ex. 2,56), it cannot be parsed successfully. It can be parsed only if it is input like this: 2.56
How can I change that?
Here is a sample code:

```
       if (double.TryParse(stringElements[i], out doubleNum))
                {
                    averageTime.Add(doubleNum);
                }
```

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`? Also show your code as well. By the way, I don't like this `.Replace` suggestions. Because if your string has `,` as a thousands separator, your code will be broken as well and your parsing will fail probably (depends on your current culture thread of course).

Comment: I think @SonerGönül's comment is correct, but as a hack, if you are sure it will be a number, can you not simply replace a single comma with a fullstop and then just parse.

Comment: What language is the user supposed to have? Bulgarian? Use appropriate `CultureInfo`. Don't replace separators with `string.Replace`!

Comment: @Mihayloff: are you wanting to support _only_ commas (that is `2,56` is valid, but `2.56` will fail) or do you want to be able to support _both_ formats simultaneously?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair yes I would like to support both formats if possible

Comment: @Mihayloff: Then `Replace` is a quick hack fix (Assuming thousands separators are not an issue for you). Off the top of my head, maybe something more permanent would be to _try_ parsing with one Culture (decimals) and if it fails, _then_ try parsing with a different Culture (commas), and if that fails, assume the input is garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the comma by '.' like this :

save your number in variable X , then

```
if (double.TryParse((X).Replace(",", "."), out tmp))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with "."

```
Convert.ToDouble("2,56".Replace(",", "."));
```